# Received power for free space optic (FSO)

Tags: attenuation

I am facing a problem with the calculation of received power in FSO.
I have calculated the received power for free space optic (FSO) using the equation:

[image]

Lsystem (system loss) is set to 8dB. PTotal can be calculated as:

[image]

where Ntx (number of receiver) = 1 and PTx (transmitted power) =7.78 dBm. LGeo (geographical loss) can be calculated as:

[image]

[image]

where d2R (receiver diameter) = 0.07m, l=1, θ (divergence angle) =0.05mrad and Nr (number of receiver) =1.

The problem is that I got received power = 10.72 dBm which is illogical value since I have setup the transmitted power = 7.78dBm. As my understanding, the received power must be lower than transmitted power.

I hope that anyone may help me to understand this situation.
For your information, I refer this paper for the calculation: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6015903

Thank you.

**EDIT**
This is my calculation coded in Python code:

```
d1=0.035
d2=0.07
NRX= 1 # no. of receiver lenses, site B
ARX=((math.pi*(d2**2))/4)*NRX
beam=0.05 #beam divergence
L=1   

geo=((4*(ARX))/(np.pi*((beam*L)**2))) # site A
geometric_loss=-(10*np.log10(geo))
print ("Geometric loss",geometric_loss,"\n")

PTX=7.78
Ptotal=PTX+10*np.log10(1)#change number of transmitter here
Lsystem=0
PRX=Ptotal-Lsystem-geometric_loss
print ("Received power",PRX)
```

Output:

```
Geometric loss -2.92256071356 

Received power 10.7025607136
```

Comment: Your first equation assumes Lgeo will be expressed as a positive number, but your 3rd equation calculates a negative number. Did you account for this in your calculation?

Comment: Notes on Python code: 1. `pi` is defined in numpy so no no need to pull in a 2nd library to get it. 2. `O` is a shitty name for a variable.

Comment: 3. Your code uses a divergence of 0.05 rad, not 0.05 mrad. What is the correct number for your problem?

Comment: I follow the setup in this paper regarding the receiver diameter and beam divergence angle. As for my understanding, 0.05 is in mrad https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12200-014-0392-8

Comment: if you want 0.05 mrad, then in your code you should have `O = 0.00005`, not `O = 0.05`. The way you use `O` to calculate the beam diameter, you need `O` to be radians, not mrad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > $$L_{geo}=-10\log_{10} \frac{4A_R}{\pi(l\theta)^2}$$

This equation is valid when the area of the receiver is (substantially) smaller than the beam diameter.

With your values ($\theta=0.05\ {\rm mrad}$ at distance 1 m, and $A_R=0.015\ {\rm m}^2$), this is not true and this equation can't be used. You can probably just assume $L_{geo}=0$ with these values.

But 0.05 mrad is an **extremely** well collimated beam. Maybe the value should be 50 mrad?

**Edit**

Your $L_{geo}$ term is just accounting for the fact that the receiver is smaller than the optical beam. You could re-write it as

$$L_{geo}=-10\log_{10}\frac{A_R}{A_B}$$

where $A_B$ is the area of the beam spot in the plane of the receiver.

Even with 50 mrad (as used in your Python code), the beam spot at 1 meter will have a diameter of 0.05 m. Since your receiver diameter is 0.07 m, under this approximation you can assume you essentially capture the entire beam with your receiver, and $L_{geo} = 0\ {\rm dB}$.

In the real world of course you wouldn't get perfect coupling. To get the actual coupling loss, you'd need a better model for the beam intensity as a function of transverse position, you'd need to know how well centered the beam is on the receiver, how accurately the receiver is pointed toward the source, etc.

If you're just getting the loss at 1 m to be able to compare with what it would be at 10 m and 100 m, assuming $L_{geo}$ of 0 dB at 1 m is probably good enough.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have attached calculation in the question. Is it possible if I maintain 0.05 mrad and get logical received power value?

Comment: @Afir, I take it back about the sign error, I got confused there.

Comment: Put negative sign for the geometrical loss? `geometric_loss=-(10*np.log10(geo))`?

Comment: Yes. Then when $A_R < A_B$, $L_{geo}$ will be positive.